# Using navigator.notification.alert instead of normal js alert

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, onesignal

I develop a phonegap app, and I get some ugly js alerts from `onesignal` from these 2 settings:

```
// Show an alert box if a notification comes in when the user is in your app.
window.plugins.OneSignal.setSubscription(true);

//activating the reception of push notification when the app is working also
window.plugins.OneSignal.enableNotificationsWhenActive(true);
```

Can i customize these, so i use cordovas `navigator.notification.alert` instead of the normal js `alert`.

Comment: I honestly don't know what your question is.

Comment: i tried making it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be customized. First you should set enableNotificationsWhenActive to false.

Next, follow the documentation for the [notificationOpenedCallback](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/phonegap--cordova-sdk-api#notificationOpenedCallback) and run `navigator.notification.alert(jsonData.message)` when `isActive` is true.